# SQL count referrals for each user

Tags: sql

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(referrer) as refs, SUM(amount) as total, contracts.id, userid, fine
FROM contracts
JOIN users ON contracts.userid = users.id
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY userid
```

my users table :

```
id | username | referrer (int)
1  | test     | 2
2  | drekorig | 
3  | maximili | 2
```

my contracts table:

```
id ! userid | amount | fine       | active
1  | 1      | 50     | 23/10/2018 | 1
2  ! 2      | 120    | 24/10/2018 | 1
3  | 2      | 150    | 24/10/2018 | 1
```

How do I get the count of referrals for each User? My query actually gets the number of contracts instead...

Expected result:

```
refs | total | id | userid | fine
0    | 0     | 1  | 1      | 23/10/2018
2    | 270   | 2  | 2      | 24/10/2018
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: I added some sample data

Comment: Great! Specify the expected result too (having that table data.)

Comment: added expected result too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a464d/5

```
SELECT r.count as refs, 
   SUM(amount) as total, 
   MAX(c.id), 
   u.id, 
   MAX(fine)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT referrer, COUNT(*) `count`
    FROM users
    GROUP BY referrer
 ) r
ON u.id = r.referrer
JOIN contracts c 
ON c.userid = u.id
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: why SUM 'fine' ?

Comment: @DregKorig I hav e no idea what is that field is for, but you should either apply aggregation function against the column or add it to the `GROUP BY` list.  So in your case you provided some data - you have 2 different dates in `fine` column for the same use - what do you expect to get as a result when `GROUP BY u.id` ?

Comment: I updated the main post with some sample data. Anyway your query not working, the count is '1' for every user, while as you can see from sample data, it should be 2 for ID 2, and 0 for others